# How can I go back to Texinfo native mode

Tags: auctex, texinfo, el-get

I have a `early-init.el` file with:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-initialize)
  (package-install 'el-get)
  (require 'el-get))

(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
(el-get 'sync)
```

If I don't put the last line `(el-get 'sync)`then I have no problem getting those commands [Inserting Frequently Used Commands](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/texinfo-3.9/html_chapter/texinfo_toc.html#TOC14) in a `.texi` file...

but, if I put `(el-get 'sync)` then `C-c C-c` runs the command `TeX-command-master` (found in
Texinfo-mode-map), which is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp
function in ‘tex-buf.el’ and I no longer have access to previous commands.

As I understand the problem comes from AUCTeX which includes a major mode for editting Texinfo files. This major mode is not the same mode as the native Texinfo mode of Emacs, although they have the same name.

How can I go back to Texinfo native mode ?

(Emacs Version 27.1 (9.0) on macOS BigSur Version 11.2)

Comment: Something in the rest of your config is loading `auctex` which redefines `texinfo-mode`.

Comment: @FranBurstall It can't be that. I have renamed my `init.el` file to exclude it so the only config file loaded is `early-init.el`

Comment: Is `auctex` mentioned in `~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes`?  I can't remember how `el-get` works but it could be that the sync activates `auctex` which then overloads `texinfo-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- `M-x customize-variable` Customize variable: TeX-modes
- uncheck texinfo-mode
- State: Save for Future Sessions